# filter array results with condition on ruby on rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sunspot

I have this action for in my **posts_controller.rb**:

```
def index
   @search = Post.solr_search do |s|
     s.fulltext params[:search]
     s.keywords params[:search]
     s.order_by :created_at, :desc
     s.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 1

   end
   @posts = @search.results
   ).page(params[:page]).per(20)
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
    format.json { render :json => @posts }
  end 
 end
```

the instance variable `@posts` is an array.

Post model have an attribute `language`.

I want get in array `@posts` only posts with `@post.language == "en"`

**I am using mongoid odm.**

How can I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed. I have added this condition to sunspot:

```
       if params[:locale].present?
        s.with(:language, params[:locale])
       else
        params[:locale] = I18n.locale
        s.with(:language, params[:locale])
       end
```

so the method would be:

```
def index
   @search = Post.solr_search do |s|
     s.fulltext params[:search]
     s.keywords params[:search]
     s.order_by :created_at, :desc
     s.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 1

         if params[:locale].present?
           s.with(:language, params[:locale])
          else
           params[:locale] = I18n.locale
           s.with(:language, params[:locale])
         end

   end
   @posts = @search.results
   ).page(params[:page]).per(20)
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
    format.json { render :json => @posts }
  end 


 end
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

Enumerable is your answer!

```
@en_posts = @posts.find_all { |post| post.language == 'en' }
```

Comment: Why is post.language an instance of `MicrofuncsController` instead of an instance of `String`?

Comment: sorry but I get error `undefined method eq for #<PostsController:0xbefd318>` I am using **mongoid**

Comment: Sorry was an error with other project. Fixed the comment error

Comment: In `rails c`, what does it show when you do `Post.first.language.class`? It still doesn't make sense why post.language would give you a reference to your controller when you are working with a model object, mongoid or no.

Comment: `1.9.3p125 :005 > Post.first.language.class
 => String`

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a problem with my code. String doesn't have the eq method. Changed to == and now it should be good!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scope it under `@posts` you can do:

```
@posts.where(language: 'en')
```

Or in a generic way

```
Post.where(language: 'en')
```

Comment: Sorry but I use mongoid and `@posts` is an array. It does not works fine with where, or find methods with arrays.

Comment: Ups, may bad, sorry. I didn't see the bold mongoid part, let me edit

Comment: Does `@search.results` returns a `Mongoid::Criteria`?